# Making a custom dirlisting in PS2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Please consider the following directory tree:

```
root
    dir1
        dir11
            x.L01 12kb
            x.L02 10kb
        dir12
            dir122
                a.jpg 5kb
                b.xls 3kb
                c.bmp 3kb
    dir2
        a.L01 100kb
        a.L02 200kb
        a.L03  50kb
    dir3
        dir31
    dir4
```

There are 3 possible cases:

1. a (sub)dir is empty; `root/dir3/dir31` and `root/dir4`
2. a (sub)dir contains (only) `L0x` files, where `x` is a number; `root/dir1/dir11` and `root/dir2`
3. a (sub)dir has files, but not of the `L0x`-kind

The desired output is a custom directory listing with 3 columns:

1. filepath
2. filesize
3. lefcount (see below)

The logic is as follows:

1. if a (sub)dir is empty, do not list the dir
2. if a (sub)dir contains (only) `L0x` files, only list the first one (`root/dir1/dir11/x.L01`) *but* count the number of and total filesize of all `L01`s
3. if a (sub)dir has other files, list the dir, *but* count the number of and total filesize of all files

So the example output would be:

```
path                      size     count
----------------------------------------
root/dir1/dir11/x.L01      22kb        2
root/dir1/dir12/dir122     11kb        3
root/dir2/a.L01           350kb        3
```

I'm just beginning powershell, and have come up with the following, which is not much but (a) am I going in the right direction? and (b) how to proceed from here?

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\root" -Recurse |
Foreach-Object {
    If ($_.PSIsContainer) {
        Get-ChildItem $_.fullname |
        Foreach-Object {
            Write-Host $_.fullname
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if a dir has both `L0x` files AND other files?

Comment: Do the `L0x` files go passed 9? `.L11`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I would say that is covered by logic condition 3 since 2 uses the word _only_

Comment: How do you determine which L0X is the first one?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen dirs *only* contain `L0x` files *or* other files. @Matt Yes, in theory to can go up to `.L99`. @Matt `L01` is the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can evolve as your needs change. This will create the desired output as a custom object that you can manipulate and export as required.

```
$rootPath = "c:\temp"
Get-ChildItem $rootPath -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
    Where-Object {(Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}|  Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count) -gt 0} |
    ForEach-Object{

        $files = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName

        $props = @{
            Path = $_.FullName
            Size = "{0:N0} KB" -f (($files | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} |  Measure-Object -Sum Length | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum) / 1024)
            Count = $files | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
        }

        If($files.Extension -match "L\d\d"){
            # These are special files and we are assuming they are alone in the directory
            # Change the path
            $props.Path = $files | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
        }

        New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props

} | Select Path,Size,Count
```

Get all the folders and files recursively for the `$rootPath`. Filter out all files and empty folders based on their immediate contents. Then build a custom object with all the requested details. If it turns out the L0X files are present then update the path with the first one found.

Currently I *assume* that all files are of L0X format. If need be we can confirm.

**Sample Output**

```
Path                                            Size     Count
----                                            ----     -----
C:\temp\win64                                   1,092 KB     2
C:\temp\Empy\Stuff\New Text Document - Copy.L01 0 KB         2
```

Comment: I just noticed, that whenever I have more than 1 `L0x` file in a directory, your script outputs the foldername, and not the path of the first `LEF`. So, in my example: `root/dir1/dir11/      22kb        2` instead of `root/dir1/dir11/x.L01      22kb        2`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pr0no Sorry about that. It's just another `where-object` I need to add to omit folders from that selection. Check that again. If not i will test myself

Comment: @Pr0no sorry about that. Will test after lunch

Comment: @Pr0no I just tried again with my updated code and it worked properly... Did you see the change on the line `$props.Path = $files | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} .....`? This happened because a folder was in the same directory as the L0X files. So I told path update code to omit folders when it was calculating.

Comment: yes, I ran your updated code..it's weird and I will check it against the actual folders that I'm running later on. Let me get back to you over the weekend with a better understanding of your code and my folderstructure. If you could check back here on monday, that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I didn't get the Fanatic badge by not spending time here.